# Laravel hasOne (one to one relationship)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to learn Laravel-> one to one relationship.

In given code link(join) should be dependent on name(user2s table) and title(post2s table) but the link(join) is dependent on my_id(user2s table) and title(post2s table)

My full codes

**Migrations:-**

user2s table

```
Schema::create('user2s', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('my_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

post2u table:

```
Schema::create('post2s', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->tinyInteger('is_admin');
    });
```

**Model User2**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'my_id'; 


public function postx(){

    return $this->hasOne(Post2::class, 'title', 'name');
}
```

**My Route Code**

```
Route::get('user/{id}/post', function($id){

    return User2::find($id)->postx;

});
```

http://localhost:8000/user/abc/post

error: Trying to get property of non-object

**user2s table**
[image]

**post2s table**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what is your issue.

1. error: Trying to get property of non-object, it means it can't find the result. The result object is `null`, so when you looking for `null->postx`, it can't get them anything.
2. You search for `User2::find($id)`, when you use `find()`, it is looking for primary key. And you `User2` Model primary key is `my_id`, and you are looking for Post2->title. It not able to find it.

More infor about `find()`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Since you are looking for the `Post2` title. And you are referencing from `User2`. It is not correct.

What you should do is

In your route.php

```
Route::get('user/{title}/post', function($title){

    //return Post2::all();
    $post = Post2::with('userx')->where('title', $title)->first();
    dump($post); 
    dump($post->userx)//<- you can get user info via 
});
```

In `Post2` Model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post2 extends Model
{

    public function userx(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User2::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```